# Tensor calculus - gradient of the Jacobian determinant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant, vector-analysis, tensors, jacobian

Given an invertible coordinate transform between a set of coordinates $\{y^1, ..., y^n \}$ and $\{x^1, ..., x^n \}$ where $y^i = y^i(x^1,...,x^n)$ and $x^i = x^i(y^1,...,y^n)$ for each $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, I am trying to prove the following formula for the gradient of the Jacobian determinant:

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^l} \left|\dfrac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\right| = \dfrac{\partial^2y^\alpha}{\partial x^l \partial x^\beta}\dfrac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial y^\alpha} \left|\dfrac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\right|$$

For reference, this is from a problem in p.87 of Tensor Analysis: Theory and Application by Ivar Stephen Sokolnikoff. I've tried using Jacobi's identity but I'm not sure whether it's applicable here, and using the co-factor expansion definition of the determinant but it hasn't led me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A:U\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to GL_n(\Bbb{R})\subset M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ be a smooth invertible-matrix-valued function defined on an open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then, the composite mapping $\det\circ A$, or simply $\det A$ is also smooth and we can investigate its partial derivatives. Well, fix a point $p\in U$. Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (\det A)}{\partial x^l}\bigg|_p&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\det A(p+te_l),
\end{align}
where $e_l=(0,\dots, 1, \dots, 0)$ with the $1$ in the $l^{th}$ spot. Now, we calculate:
\begin{align}
\det\left(A(p+te_l)\right)&=\det\left(A(p)+ t\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^l}(p)+ \mathcal{O}(t^2)\right)\\
&=\det\left(A(p)\right)\cdot \det\left(I+t\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^l}(p)\cdot A(p)^{-1}+ \mathcal{O}(t^2)\right)\\
&= \det(A(p))\cdot \left(1+ t\,\text{trace}\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^l}(p)\cdot A(p)^{-1}\right)+ \mathcal{O}(t^2)\right).
\end{align}
So, if you calculate the derivative with respect to $t$ at $t=0$, we find that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (\det A)}{\partial x^l}\bigg|_p&=\det(A(p))\cdot \text{trace}\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^l}(p)\cdot A(p)^{-1}\right),
\end{align}
or $\frac{\partial (\det A)}{\partial x^l}=\det A\cdot \text{trace}\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^l}\cdot A^{-1}\right)$ for short if you suppress the point of evaluation.
Can you specialize to the case of $A=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$?

---

Btw the formula $\det(I+tB)=1+t\cdot\text{trace}(B)+\mathcal{O}(t^2)$ is easily proved if $B$ is triangular. In the general case, you can perform a similarity transformation (by passing to the Jordan canonical form over $\Bbb{C}$ for instance) and then deduce the result. Or... you can directly apply the Leibniz formula/cofactor expansion and induction or any of the other brute-force methods.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: The formula you give at the end for the derivative of the det. is [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)